# Stored procedure to Add Multiple Records at once by generating custom column value based on inputs

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

For SQL Server 2016 I am trying to write stored procedure to add multiple records at once by generating custom column value based on inputs  with description given below

Following is my table definition for SQL Server 2016

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Box]
(
    [BoxId] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [HouseId] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [nchar](10) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Box] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BoxId] ASC, [HouseId] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Another table used is House with following details

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[House]
(
    [HouseId] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Prefix] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Tasks is to insert records into `Box` table. SQL query will be converted to a stored procedure. There is no identity column and autoincrement. `HouseId` is available as input and number of records to insert (`BoxCount`) as input and `BoxId` is to generated for each insert.

`BoxID` column has the format of `Prefix + Number`; `Prefix` is to be referred to from the `House` table), `Number` should be auto incremented by one than previous record.

Sample values for `BoxId` columns are

```
WOOO1-1
WOOO1-2
WOOO1-1000
WOOO1-1004
```

The stored procedure defined is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Insert_Boxes 
    @HouseId nvarchar(20),
    @BoxCount int   /* Numbers of Box records to insert*/
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @BoxId = "?"

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Box] ([BoxId], [HouseId], [Status])
    VALUES
         /*BoxId to be generated. BoxId has format Prefix-Number */
         (@BoxId, @HouseId, 'Open')
END
```

Query/stored procedure is to be written to insert n number of records into `Box` table when input available is `HouseId`, and number of records to inserts (prefix to be taken from the `House` table). `Status` value is always 'Open'.

For example for `House` table data as below

```
HouseId   Prefix    Address
----------------------------
   1      W0001     Address1
   2      W0002     NULL
```

This is the expected output for `HouseId = 1` and `BoxCount = 5` input to proposed stored procedure:

```
BoxId    HouseId    Status
---------------------------
W0001-1     1       Open      
W0001-2     1       Open      
W0001-3     1       Open      
W0001-4     1       Open      
W0001-5     1       Open
```

What changes are needed to the stored procedure to get desired functionality? The stored procedure will be called from C# Winforms application using `System.Data.SqlClient`.

Edit 1
Based on answer provided by Aaron Bertrand I have updated stored procedure as below

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Insert_Boxes]
 @HouseId nvarchar(20),
 @BoxPrefix nvarchar(5),
 @BoxCount int   /* Numbers of Box records to insert*/
AS
BEGIN
    

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Box]
           ([BoxId]
           ,[HouseId]
           ,[Status])
         SELECT TOP (@BoxCount) [BinId] = CONCAT(@BoxPrefix, '-',
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])),
    [HouseId]  =  @HouseId ,
    [Status] = N'Open'
  FROM sys.all_columns
  ORDER BY [object_id];
END
```

and executes it as shown below

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[usp_Insert_Boxes]
        @HouseId = N'1',
        @BoxPrefix = N'W0001',
        @BoxCount = 5

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Although it works for first execution, for second invocation it it shows following error
State 1, Procedure usp_Insert_Boxes, Line 11 [Batch Start Line 2]
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Box'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Box'. The duplicate key value is (W0001-1, 1).

However requirement is that stored procedure should check whether HouseId and BoxId combination does not already exists and if exists if needs to generate new set of non existing incremental BoxIds for insertion. Also for each HouseId, Number part of BoxId should start from 1 and then incrementally onwards.  May be I have not stressed this part enough in my question.

### BoxId  HouseId    Status

```
W0001-1     1       Open      
W0001-2     1       Open      
W0001-3     1       Open      
W0001-4     1       Open      
W0001-5     1       Open    
W0002-1     2       Open      
W0002-2     2       Open      
W0002-3     2       Open      
W0002-4     2       Open      
W0002-5     2       Open
```

Comment: `@BoxCount int ` Typically one would think of a loop to iterate <boxcount> number of times. Perhaps that should be your first attempt. Looping is uncommon in well-written SQL but it seems you're still learning basic tsql so the WHILE loop is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of straightforward ways to generate a set given an integer value (at least within reason):

```
DECLARE @i int = 5;

SELECT TOP (@i) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
  FROM sys.all_columns
  ORDER BY [object_id];
```

Or a recursive CTE:

```
DECLARE @i int = 5;

;;;/* leading semi-colons are intentional */;;;WITH cte(n) AS
(
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL SELECT n + 1 FROM cte WHERE n < @i
)
SELECT n FROM cte;
```

(If `@i` can be > 100 you'll need `OPTION (MAXRECURSION` hint.)

Both of these produce this output:

| n |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=3781d64270e3a6abde87eb227e7a85f6)

So you could mix either of those that with whatever values go on every row, e.g.

```
DECLARE @i int = 5; -- input param

-- determined inside the procedure?
DECLARE @BoxPrefix nvarchar(20) = N'W0001-';

--INSERT dbo.[Box](BoxId,HouseId,[Status])
SELECT TOP (@i) BoxId = CONCAT(@BoxPrefix, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])),
    HouseId  = 1,
    [Status] = N'Open'
  FROM sys.all_columns
  ORDER BY [object_id];
```

This produces:

| BoxId | HouseId | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| W0001-1 | 1 | Open |
| W0001-2 | 1 | Open |
| W0001-3 | 1 | Open |
| W0001-4 | 1 | Open |
| W0001-5 | 1 | Open |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=706d4920b8a471d4702a0a608d2243f5)